# Knockout not sending List of object from post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a C# object like

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfEvent { get; set; }

    public List<Children> Applicants { get; set; }

    public string SelectedChoice { get; set; }

}

public class Children
{
    public string CoverageFor { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }

}
```

then My html is like this.

```
            <div class="control-group span4">
                <label class="control-label" for="4">County</label><select name="county" id="4" data-bind="options: county, optionsText:'County', value:selectedCounty, optionsValue: 'FIPSCountyCode' ,  optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

            </div>
        </div>
@*--------------------------------------- some more things --------------*@
            <div class="row-fluid dependent " data-bind='foreach: applicants'>
                       <div class="control-group span4">
                        <label class="control-label" for="5">
                            Coverage
                            for
                        </label>
                        <select name="coverageFor" id="5" data-bind="options: coverages, value:coverageFor, optionsText:'name', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group span4">
                        <label class="control-label" for="6">
                            Date of
                            Birth
                        </label>

                        <input id="6" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="input-small" data-date-blur="true" data-regex="^((\d{0,2})|(\d{1,2}/?\d{0,2})|(\d{1,2}/?\d{1,2}/?\d{0,4}))$"
                               type="text" data-bind="value: dateofBirth"/>



                    </div>
                    @*<a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeApplicant, enable: $root.applicants().length > 1'>Remove</a>*@
                    <!-- ko if: $index() != 0 -->
                    <a href='#' data-bind="click: $root.removeApplicant">Remove</a>
                    <!-- /ko -->

            </div>
```

Then my script is like following

```
$(function () {
    viewModel.zipCode.subscribe(function (value) {
        $.get("/api/xx/GetCounties?zipCode=" + value, null, viewModel.county, 'json');
    }.bind(this));
});


var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.zipCode = ko.observable();
    self.dateOfEvent = ko.observable();
    self.isValidZip = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();


    //Enrollment reasons
    self.enrollmentReasons = ko.observableArray(new Array());
    $.get("/api/myApi/GetEnrollmentReason", null, self.enrollmentReasons, 'json');

    //county from Zipcode subscribed
    self.county = ko.observableArray(new Array());
    $.get("/api/myApi/GetCounties?zipCode=" + self.zipCode, null, self.county, 'json');


    self.applicants = ko.observableArray(new Array());
    self.applicants.push(new Children());

    //$.get("/api/myApi/IsInServiceArea?zipCode=" + value, null, ViewModel.isValidZip, 'json');


    //operations
    self.addApplicant = function () { self.applicants.push(new Children()) };
    self.removeApplicant = function (Children) { self.applicants.remove(getaquoteapplicant) };

    self.save = function () {
        var m = ko.mapping.toJS(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self));
        $.ajax({
            url: '/mypostingpage/start',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(m),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);

            }
        });
    }

}

var Children= function () {
    var self = this;
    self.coverageFor = ko.observable();
    self.tobaccoUser = ko.observable();
    self.dateofBirth = ko.observable();

    self.coverages = ko.observableArray([
        { name: "Self" },
        { name: "Spouse/Life Partner" },
        { name: "Son" },
        { name: "Daughter" },
        { name: "Sibling" },
        { name: "Other Eligible Person" }
    ]);


};   

viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

When I get my post from the call
on the controller.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult Start(MyModel model)  <------- has all the values but the Children's property values not in.
{

    //Stuff I will return 
}
```

When I get the `MyModel` back, it will have all the values but the Children will show how many children I have properly, but the values didn't change. All the properties for children will have the default values.

Does anyone know how I can get the List properties hydrated properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't mention `optionValue` on this select

```
<select name="coverageFor" id="5" data-bind="options: coverages, value:coverageFor, optionsText:'name', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

so it will return

```
coverageFor: { name: "self" }
```

and this is not valid at your server side, since its expecting a `string` not object

replace it with

```
<select name="coverageFor" id="5" data-bind="options: coverages, value:coverageFor, optionsText:'name', optionsValue:'name', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```